# git + dropbox problem

Tags: git, dropbox

*~/Project = C:\Users\Алексей Резников\My Projects\netbeans\CourseProject2011*
*~/Dropbox = C:\Users\Алексей Резников\Dropbox\Институт\4ый курс\7ой семестр\Курсовая Работа*

I have created a project and a repository for it.

```
~/Project> git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

added a remote
`~/Project>git remote add dropbox "~/Dropbox/course_project_2011.git"`

then `git push dropbox master` it responded *everything is up-to-date*

Dropbox synchronized the repository. I have copied the project to another PC, etc. But when i try to run

`C:\Users\User\Desktop\Course Project>git clone -o dropbox "C:\Users\User\Dropbox
\Курсовая Работа\course_project_2011.git"`

i get this:

```
Cloning into course_project_2011...
fatal: 'C:\Users\User\Dropbox\???????? ??????\course_project_2011.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`
```

Throws the same error, doesn't matter if the Project is initialized or not

Any ideas? I am very new to git, so.. :c

both PC's are running w7, git-1.7.3.2-utf8-20110213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never a good idea to use russian in path. Also since you are using windows it's a good idea to avoid spaces in path too.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output, I'd eliminate "Курсовая Работа" from the path to the repo and try it again. That would help confirm whether it's some kind of character encoding problem, as it appears to be.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers stated, git does not play well with Unicode characters, especially on Windows

Try to [install version 1.7.6](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list), I think it has fixes in this area.